# huge files /var/log/messages and /var/log/warn

Tags: logs, opensuse, nouveau

After an update last week, something is bloating up the messages and warn files in my /var/log/ folder. Closer inspection revealed that the following line was printed to the files every 0.000001 seconds resulting in 3 files of 20GB filling up completely my disk space:

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: PBDMAO: 81206000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 2 [003fc71000 X[1722]] subc 0 mthd 0000 data ffffffff
```

I am not an experienced user and have no idea how to fix this.

I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed (version ID: 20191101) on a Lenovo T430 laptop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a known bug on `nouveau` driver (if i remember well, this is the opensource driver for NVidia graphic cards).

Source: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99900

To fix this you can:

- Use `logrotate` or a `cron` job to flush logs passed a given size.

**or**

- Tweak your `syslog` configuration to avoid logging this.

**or**

- Totally disable `syslog` (rarely usefull on a desktop system).

**or**

- Stop using `nouveau` driver (install proprietary one or use `vesa`).

Comment: Could you possibly provide a step-by-step for a permanent solution, please?

Comment: Not sure what it's called on openSuse but look for a proprietary Nvidia driver. Which one exactly also depends on your display card; the beginning of your `Xorg.log` or similar should identify the model.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a permanent solution, but to boot-up past the error messages:

- On
- F2
- Boot Manager
- F2 + Shift

Comment: The system boots, your answer ist not the answer to his question.

Comment: Not quite; I was getting the exact same errors. This is how you can `Boot in Insecure Mode`, so as to then download and install drivers. A useful step nonetheless.